# PHP static function does not die

Tags: php, mysql

```
class mySql {
 static function query($q){
  return mysql_query($q)or die(mysql_error());
 }
}
```

class MySql

```
echo mySql::query('SELECT * FROM unknown_table');
```

it must die and display the mysql error but its not.

do static functions really go that way?

Comment: nothing. it shows nothing just the normal page it dies when i append or die(mysql_error()); at the latter statement

Comment: What is the full code? In this context, `mysql_query` shouldn't even work as there isn't any connection established yet. But it should still print an error, though. I just tested my own class and it works correctly, the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: as far as i understand it. the 3rd line is where the part where the script dies .if i try mySql::query('SELECT * FROM unknown_table')or die(); that is where it dies

Answer (score 1):

[Works for me](http://codepad.org/X3On8pr8).

(basically for the `die()` to work, the `mysql_query()` needs to return *falsy* - putting `false` there lets me test your [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

Show me your code relevant to your problem, please.

Does it work with a valid query?

Comment: yes it does ..ill put it online first and show you the codes wait a bit

Answer (score 0):

guess im just stupid

my load_class() function does not load the class properly
i forgot to configure my Configuration file and set the base uri to the current folder lol
maybe i should delete this one. oh stupidity /facepalm

[image]

sorry for bothering everyone xD